# Loading proper density images from archive into ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an archive file that I am downloading, unarchiving and reading and it may or may not contain images, including images for screens with a higher pixel density.

What is the best way to use/choose the images with a higher pixel density on higher pixel density screens? Is there some way that the android platform has built in, or will I have to check the pixel density of the device at runtime and decide on the proper image manually?

Or, is there a different way?

Comment: AFAIK you'll have to do it manually. The platform provides a way to do it with pre-packaged resources (by putting them in drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi etc...) But I do not think there is any built in way to do it to resources you are acquiring at runtime.

Comment: @FoamyGuy Okay. I figured I would utilize this resource here to see if I could save myself some time and also optimize the app a little at the same time. Thanks!